How to create a dynamic user form with Devise and Hotwire
I have devise installed as authentication system in my Rails 7 app. I want to be able to create dynamic forms for organization and individual user types using hotwire. That is, when I click on individual option, a number of form fields should be displayed while others are hidden. I should be able to do this both on new and edit registration pages.
Since I am attempting to use hotwire to make this work, I have the a navigate stimulus controller
navigate_controller.js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

/*
 * Usage
 * =====
 *
 * add data-controller="navigate" to the turbo frame you want to navigate
 *
 * Action (add to radio input):
 * data-action="change->navigate#to"
 * data-url="/new?input=yes"
 *
 */
export default class extends Controller {
  to(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { url } = e.target.dataset;

    this.element.src = url;
  }
}

In my signup page, I have a conditional statement that wraps the organization fields and also turbo frame tag which points to the navigate controller.
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <%= turbo_frame_tag "account_types", data: { controller: "navigate" } do %>

    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <%= f.label :account_type, value: 'individual', class: 'form-check form-check-inline' do %>
        <%= f.radio_button :account_type, 'individual', class: 'form-check-input', data: { action: "change->navigate#to", url: new_account_registration_path({ account: { account_type: "individual" } }) } %>
        <label class="form-check-label">Individual</label>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.label :account_type, value: 'organization', class: 'form-check form-check-inline' do %>
        <%= f.radio_button :account_type, 'organization', class: 'form-check-input', data: { action: "change->navigate#to", url: new_account_registration_path({ account: { account_type: "company" } }) } %>
        <label class="form-check-label">Organization</label>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <% if @account.organization? %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :organization_name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :organization_name, autocomplete: "Organization name" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        Organization Type
        <%= f.label :organization_type, value: 'base', class: 'form-check form-check-inline' do %>
          <%= f.radio_button :organization_type, 'base', class: 'form-check-input' %>
          <label class="form-check-label">Base</label>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.label :organization_type, value: 'ministry', class: 'form-check form-check-inline' do %>
          <%= f.radio_button :organization_type, 'ministry', class: 'form-check-input' %>
          <label class="form-check-label">Ministry</label>
        <% end %>
      </div>

    <% else %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :firstname %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :firstname, autocomplete: "firstname" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :surname %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :surname, autocomplete: "surname" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username, autocomplete: "username" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :state %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :state, autocomplete: "state" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :country %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :country, autocomplete: "country" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :bio %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :bio, autocomplete: "bio" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

I have also generated devise registrations controller, added params to the new action
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Accounts::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    # super
    @account = Account.new configure_sign_up_params
  end

  # POST /resource
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
  # def update
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  # def cancel
  #   super
  # end

  protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :firstname, :surname, :state, :country, :bio, :account_type, :organization_name, :organization_type])
  rescue
    {}
  end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username, :firstname, :surname, :state, :country, :bio, :account_type, :organization_name, :organization_type])
  end

  # The path used after sign up.
  # def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end
end

I guess I am not customizing the devise registration controller properly for it not to work

"Dynamic" doesn't actually tell us what this code is actually supposed to accomplish. Most likely you don't need to clobber Devise like this and could just use nested attributes to handle creating the organization.

@max I mentioned that "when I click on individual option of the account type, a number of form fields should be displayed while others are hidden".. the fields that are to be displayed you be on a condition (account type).

configure_sign_up_params only adds extra parameters to permit, which devise then uses inside a corresponding action:
pp devise_parameter_sanitizer

#=>
<Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0x00007fd64171a420
 @auth_keys=[:email],
 @params=#<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"accounts/registrations", "action"=>"new"} permitted: false>,
 @permitted=
  {:sign_in=>[:email, :password, :remember_me],
   :sign_up=>[:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :account_type],
   # ^ used in Devise::RegistrationsController#create action
   :account_update=>[:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password]},
 @resource_name=:account>

sign_up_params method is what you want to use to get permitted params when registering:
class Accounts::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create, :new]

  def new
    build_resource sign_up_params
  end

  protected

  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:account_type])
  end
end

You really have to look at devise source to understand what is going on. Basic rails also works for this situation:
class Accounts::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    @account = Account.new(params.fetch(:account, {}).permit(:account_type))
  end
end


Also you're unnecessarily nesting <label> tag:
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= turbo_frame_tag "account_types", data: {controller: "navigate"} do %>
    <%= f.label :account_type_individual do %>
      <%= f.radio_button :account_type, "individual",
        data: {
          action: "change->navigate#to",
          url: new_account_registration_path(account: {account_type: "individual"})
        }
      %>
      Individual
    <% end %>

    <%= f.label :account_type_organization do %>
      <%= f.radio_button :account_type, "organization",
        data: {
          action: "change->navigate#to",
          url: new_account_registration_path(account: {account_type: "organization"})
        }
      %>
      Organization
    <% end %>

    <% if resource.account_type == "organization" %>
      # TODO: company fields
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
<% end %>


There really is no need to clobber the new method here and doing so just introduces a bunch of potential issues. If any additional logic needs to be added just pass a block to super as the super method yields. def new; super {|resource| puts "do something after the resource is created" }; end. https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/a259ff3c28912a27329727f4a3c2623d3f5cb6f2/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L11C5-L11C35
